# How to call api in top window in the child iframe when they are not the same protocol?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-domain, chromium, node-webkit

I am using nwjs. I put a iframe in the app page (top window):

```
<iframe src="aaa.com" id="contentFrame"></iframe>
```

I want to tell the app page (top window) to run some functions in the iframe (domain: aaa.com):

```
<!-- code in the iframe-->
<input type="button" value="close" onclick="window.top.close();"></input>
<input type="button" value="window.top._close" onclick="window.top._close();"></input>
```

When I click the buttons above in the iframe, I get the errors:

*Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3900" from accessing a frame with origin "file://".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.*

I tried to set this argument in the package.json:

```
"chromium-args": "--disable-web-security",
```

But it's only work for the "window.to.close();" button.

And I want to call the Native UI API in this way too:

```
require('nw.gui').gui.Window.get().minimize();
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to allow this, but you can use [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to make safe communication between frames.

```
 // in parent window
 window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.data == "closeYourSelf") window.close();
 }, false);

 // in child iframe
 $('button.close').bind('click', function (clickEv) {
   clickEv.preventDefault();
   window.top.postMessage("closeYourSelf", '*');
 });
```

Comment: Because this enables cross-origin messaging, unless the OP wants the parent window to be closed by anything sending it the message, the parent window's handler would want to check `event.origin` to whitelist message sources from which it allows closing the window.